# Is there a roadmap to port the design of the new Stack Overflow app to the Stack Exchange app?

Tags: support, android-app

I genuinely love the new design.  It's clean, vibrant, and gives me all of the things that I need to see in one place.  The only issue I have with it now is that when I look at the older app, I can't feel the same way about it; it feels dated and a bit crusty.

Is there a timeline at all to port this look over?  I really don't want the more venerable app to be left in the dust.